# If $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix then rank($A$)=rank($A^2$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-rank

"Prove that if $A$ is  a diagonalizable matrix then rank($A$)=rank($A^2$)".

This is what I had in mind:

$ D = $$ P^{-1} $  $A$ $P$ is diagonal.

$ D^2 = P^{-1} A P P^{-1} A P= P^{-1}  A^2 P$ is diagonal.

Therefore, rank($D$)=rank($D^2$).

rank($P^{-1}AP$)=rank($P^{-1}A^2P$)

$P$ is invertible, therefore rank($P$)=rank($P^{-1}$)

and rank($A$)=rank($A^2$).

Is this proof legitimate? Or is something missing?

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a lot of details:

1. Why is $\operatorname{rank}(D)=\operatorname{rank}(D^2)$?
2. How does $\operatorname{rank}(P)=\operatorname{rank}(P^{-1})$ help you?  Perhaps you need a different fact about the rank of invertible matrices.
3. There seems to be a big jump to the last line of $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A^2)$.  How did the facts that you list combine to give this equality?

Hints :

1. No where in your "proof" do you do any work.  You either need to cite theorems and show how they apply or actually do a computation.
2. Show that $D$ and $D^2$ have nonzero entries in exactly the same positions.  Use this to argue that their column spans are identical.
3. Explain why a invertible matrix will take a subspace of dimension $k$ to another subspace of dimension $k$.
4. Use 2 and 3 together to argue that the column span of $A$ and $A^2$ are identical.

Comment: You are right, how do I prove it then?

Comment: **Hint:** it's very easy to put a diagonal matrix in row echelon form. What could the row echelon form of a diagonal matrix look like? Or if you prefer, what does the kernel of a diagonal matrix look like? Once you have either: given a diagonal matrix, how can you quickly find its rank? Why does squaring the diagonal matrix give you something of the same rank, then?

Comment: Once you have the right fact about invertible matrices, the last steps are obvious.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sure, but I don't know what facts the OP knows.  Of course some of the steps that I mentioned can be replaced by the / turned into appropriate lemmas.

Comment: @MichaelBurr that was meant for the OP, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the clarification, I thought you meant it towards me!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the fact that multiplying a matrix by on the left side by the inverse of an invertible and on the right side by an invertible matrix is a rank preserving operation? So, we'd have

> $rank(P^{-1}DP) = rank(P^{-1}D^2P^{-1})\quad \Longrightarrow  \quad rank(D) = rank(D^2)$.

It is clear that the rank of $D$ and $D^2$ are equivalent, since the all the rows are clearly linearly independent. Or in other words, the entry in each pivot of the matrix is a non-zero number, which implies that the nullity of the linear operator that induces the diagonal representation is zero. Hence, the ranks are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if $A$ is diagonalisable, $A= P^{-1}DP$ implies $A^2= P^{-1}D^2P$ so $A^2$ is diagonalisable and if $c_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $a_i,$ then $c_i^{2}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ with multiplicity $a_i.$

So if $p(x)= \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n(x-c_i)^{a_i}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A,$ then $q(x)= \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n(x-c_i^{2})^{a_i}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A^2.$ The nullity of $A$ is the geometric multiplicity of $0$ as an eigenvalue and since $A$ is diagonalisable, this coincides with the algebraic multiplicity and hence the nullity of $A$ is $a_i$ if $c_i =0$ and $0$ otherwise. Similarly, the nullity of $A^2$ is $a_i$ if $c_i^{2}=0$ and $0$ otherwise. Hence nullity of $A$ = nullity of $A^2$ and thus $\text{rank}(A)= \text{rank}(A^2).$