# rank and diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wonder if the following assertion is true :

> If $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that
> $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^2)$ then $A$ is diagonalizable .

The motivation came from the question already discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147506/if-a-is-a-diagonalizable-matrix-then-ranka-ranka2) . I just tried to reverse the proof presented there but something appears wrong as some extra conditions might be necessary for the assertion to be held true . Am I correct about the assertion or some other proof might be presented ? Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$ for $n=2$, or any $n\times n$ non-nilpotent Jordan block, for that matter.

Comment: OK. If I add an extra condition , say , $A^2=A^3$ ? Can anything be said ?

Comment: @am_11235... more or less the same counterexample will work in this case, just look at the matrix with a $1$ in the $(1,2)$-place and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @am_11235... It is indeed the case that if $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^2)$ *and* $A^2 = A^3$, then $A$ is diagonalizable